# find T such that $(\ln\theta)^2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty Te^{-n\ln\theta}\frac{(n\ln\theta)^k}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I find T such that

$$(\ln\theta)^2=\sum_{t=0}^\infty Te^{-n\ln\theta}\frac{(n\ln\theta)^t}{t!}$$
But T can't be a function of $\theta$

I tried
 $$(\ln\theta)^2e^{n\ln\theta}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty T\frac{(n\ln\theta)^t}{t!}$$
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty(\ln\theta)^2\frac{(n\ln\theta)^t}{t!}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty T\frac{(n\ln\theta)^t}{t!}$$
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac{(n\ln\theta)^{t+2}}{t!}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty n^2T\frac{(n\ln\theta)^t}{t!}$$
I don't know what to do now.

### Examples

For

$$e^{-\theta}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty Te^{-n\theta}\frac{(n\theta)^t}{t!}$$
$$e^{-\theta}=e^{-n\theta}\sum_{t=0}^\infty T\frac{(n\theta)^t}{t!}$$
$$e^{\theta(n-1)}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty T\frac{(n\theta)^t}{t!}$$
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{(\theta(n-1))^t}{t!}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty T\frac{(n\theta)^t}{t!}$$
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty (\theta)^t(n-1)^t=\sum_{t=0}^\infty Tn^t\theta^t$$
$$$$

So 
$$T=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^t$$

Another example

$$(\ln\theta)=\sum_{t=0}^\infty Te^{-n\ln\theta}\frac{(n\ln\theta)^t}{t!}$$

$$T=\frac{t}{n}$$

Comment: Isn't the RHS of the first equation just $T$? What is $T$ exactly? Can it be a constant?

Comment: T can't be a constant. The RHS is the definition of Expected value $E_\theta[T]$

Comment: Fair enough, but the way it's defined, I could factor $Te^{-n \ln \theta}$ out, and the sum is just $e^{n \ln \theta}$; is the equation using some standard notation I'm probably missing? Or is it missing some parenthesis?

Comment: I wrote some examples

Comment: and I am trying to use the same method for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find coefficients $T_t(n)$ such that

$$x^2=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}{T_t(n)e^{-nx}\frac{(nx)^t}{t!}}$$

Rearranging a bit, we notice that

$$(nx)^2e^{nx}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n^2T_t(n))\frac{(nx)^t}{t!}$$

or setting $y=nx$

$$y^2e^{y}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n^2T_t(n))\frac{y^t}{t!}$$

Clearly, the coefficients $C_t=n^2T_t(n)$ cannot depend on $n$. Let's find $C_t$. These coefficients are by definition the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of the function $y^2e^y$ around $y=0$. Since

$$y^2e^y=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{t+2}}{t!}=\sum_{t=2}^{\infty}\frac{t!}{(t-2)!}\frac{y^t}{t!}$$

we find that $C_0=C_1=0~,~C_t=\frac{t!}{(t-2)!}=t(t-1)~,t > 1$, which can be trivially extended to $C_t=t(t-1)~\forall t\in\mathbb{N}$ which implies that finally:

$$T_t(n)=\frac{t(t-1)}{n^2}$$