# UMVUE of $(\ln\theta)^2$ where $p(x|\theta)=\frac{\left(\ln\theta\right)^x}{\theta x!}I_{\{0,1,2,\dots\}}(x)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let 
$$p(x|\theta)=\frac{\left(\ln\theta\right)^x}{\theta x!}I_{\{0,1,2,\dots\}}(x)\; $$

I have to find UMVUE for $h(\theta)=\ln\theta$ and for $h(\theta)=(\ln\theta)^2$

I know $T(X_1,\dots,X_n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ is complete and sufficient for $\theta$

By CRLB I found $\overline{X}$ as UMVUE for $h(\theta)=\ln\theta$  but now I don't know how to find the second one. Can you help me please?

Comment: I see you had essentially asked the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3680966/321264. What is the point of this post? You could have just quoted the original problem in the previous post.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right the first question was to solve the equation with series and the origin was this question but apparently to do it more tools are needed and it is more complex, so I looked for other simpler ways but I failed.
You're right $\theta > 1 $ Thankyou so much again.

Comment: Comparing coefficients is a good way to do this, which would be particularly helpful if you try to find unbiased estimators of higher powers of $\ln\theta$. But you made a mistake while doing this; you ought to start with $E(g(T))=\sum_j g(j) P(T=j)=(\ln\theta)^2$ and solve for the function $g(\cdot)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I didn't know that, I will try it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent distribution is just $\mathsf{Poisson}(\ln\theta)$ where I assume $\theta>1$.

So assuming $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\mathsf{Poisson}(\ln\theta)$, you have $T=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\sim \mathsf{Poisson}(n\ln\theta)$.

Now,

$$E_{\theta}(T^2)=\operatorname{Var}_{\theta}(T)+(E_{\theta}(T))^2=n\ln\theta+n^2(\ln\theta)^2\quad,\,\forall\,\theta$$

Therefore, $$E_{\theta}(T^2-T)=E_{\theta}(T^2)-E_{\theta}(T)=n^2(\ln\theta)^2\quad,\,\forall\,\theta$$

Hence the UMVUE of $(\ln\theta)^2$ is $$\widehat{(\ln\theta)^2}=\frac{T(T-1)}{n^2}$$